# Auto Relacionamento com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento

estou com o seguinte problema ao tentar fazer um auto relacionamento com Laravel 5.
Quero fazer um cadastro de usuário, onde usuários poderão ter outros usuários vinculados, criando um autorelacionamento N x N, user_user;

O usuário terá um status, e esse status é um outro model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable{

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'status_id'
];
```

...

```
class Vinculo extends Model{

protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'user_id', 'vinculo_id'
];
```

....

```
class StatusUser extends Model{

protected $fillable = [ 
    'id', 'nome',       
];
```

..

e no meu UserController eu consulta o usuário com status

```
public function show($id){  

    $result = $this->context->with('statususers')->find($id);
```

...

que retorna o json,

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "aa",
"email": "aa@email.com",
"statususers": {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Ativo"
}
```

}

..

Agora a minha questão é, como consultar todos os usuários relacionados a um usuário específico, e que nos usuários vinculados possa também ser exibido o status de cada um,

Relacionamento na classe User

```
    public function vinculos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'vinculos', 'user_id', 'vinculos_id');
}
```

...

Modifico o método show, incluindo o relacionamento vinculos

```
    public function show($id){  

    $result = $this->context->with('statususers')->with('vinculos')->find($id);
```

O Relacionamento está ok, porém não está retornando os status dos usuários vinculados, esse é o problema.

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "aa",
"email": "aa@email.com",
"remember_token": "Y7cc9OHpKalEkKivihETU2LQeNftGWZ1hqVH0v2nM1z0DZ3dUe3emwsIDxec",
"statususers": {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Ativo"
},
"vinculos": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "bb",
        "email": "bb@email.com",
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "amigo_id": 3
        }
    }
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "cc",
        "email": "cc@email.com",
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "amigo_id": 3
        }
    }
]
```

}

Essa é a grande dúvida, se o meu objeto relacionado é da classe User, porque os demais usuário não mostram também seus respectivos objetos status, igual ao registro pai dos vínculos? Vendo que todos os demais atributos da classe User são exibidos corretamente, porém falta o objeto status..

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Talvez o que você esteja querendo fazer é usar o `nested relationship`.

Trata-se de uma forma de trazer, através do método `with`, um relacionamento do relacionamento.

Exemplo: `posts` relaciona-se com `usuários`, e cada usuário tem um `país`.

No `Laravel` Poderíamos fazer assim:

```
 Post::with('usuario.pais')->get();
```

O resultado seria algo parecido com essa representação:

```
[
   'id'    => 1,
   'texto' => 'Meu post',
   'usuario_id' => 1,
   'usuario' => [
      'id'   => 1,
      'nome' => 'Wallace',
      'pais_id' => 1,
      'pais' => [ 'id' => 1, 'Brasil',]
   ]

]
```

Outro detalhe. Esqueci de mencionar que você não deve utilizar os métodos `with` em sequência, pois internamente eles não utilizam o `$this` para referenciar a própria instância, mas usa-se `new static` (eu já olhei o código fonte da classe `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`).

Você deve passar todos os argumentos de uma vez para `with`, e ele também deve ser o primeiro a ser chamado.

Exemplo (certos):

```
 Post::with('comments.people', 'images')->where('id', '=', 1);

 Post::with(['comments.people', 'images'])->where('id', '=', 1);
```

Exemplos (errado):

```
 // isso anula a query anterior

 Post::where('id', '=', 1)->with('comments.people', 'images');


// isso só faz funcionar o último with

Post::with('comments.people')->with('images');
```

Os outros métodos como `where`, `lists`, `get` e afins, são da classe `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Elas são chamadas através do método mágico `__call` presente na classe `Model` (o alias dela é `Eloquent`). Já o método `with` é um método estático, e, portanto, ele só serve para criar uma nova instância do próprio model com os relacionamentos que serão carregados pré-definidos.

Para mostrar que eu não estou dando nenhuma informação incorreta, basta conferir o código no `github`, na linha `672`.

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.1/Eloquent/Model.php

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde galera, 
Então Wallace, não era bem isso que eu queria, mas já consegui resolver.

Deu uma grande vasculhada na documentação do Laravel, e acabei vendo que por padrão os relacionamentos usam a forma Eager Load, que somente irá carregar os objetos quando forem acessados, isso por questões de performance e tal..

Pro meu caso, tive que forçar o carregamento usando o Lazy Load, que carrega todas as instâncias, fazendo com que todos os objetos fossem listados da forma como eu queria,

o resultado obtido foi esse:"

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "aa",
"email": "aa@email.com",
"statususers": {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Ativo"
},
"vinculos": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "bb",
        "email": "bb@email.com",
        "statususers": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Ativo"
         },
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "amigo_id": 3
        }
    }
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "cc",
        "email": "cc@email.com",
        "statususers": {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Ativo"
         },
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "amigo_id": 3
        }
    }
]
```

---

Agora está sendo listado os status dos usuários vinculados.

Valeu, obrigado!

Comment: Mas você força o carregamento dos relacionamentos fazendo do jeito que eu fiz. Eu não entendi o que há de errado com minha resposta. Você mostrou o seu json, mas não mostrou como chegou ao resultado. É bom postar aqui para que outros entendam como resolveu o problema.

Comment: Só vou tirar o negativo quando tiver a solução real do problema. Demonstrar como o retorno esperado dos dados não é a solução do problema, você precisa mostrar o código com que você chegou a isso.

Answer (score 1):

Só fazer um `hasMany`.

Exemplo: eu sou uma pessoa e tenho varios filhos, meus dependentes que são pessoas..

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pessoa extends Model
{
  // id, usuario_id, nome, rg, cpf, foto_url, data_nascimento, endereco_id, responsavel_id, fornecedor_id

  protected $fillable =
  ['usuario_id', 'nome', 'rg', 'cpf', 'foto_url', 'data_nascimento', 'responsavel_id', 'fornecedor_id'];

  public $timestamps = false;


  public function dependentes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pessoa','responsavel_id');
  }

  public function contatos()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contato');
  }

}
```